# Exporting Excel sheet to Access db macro

Tags: excel, ms-access, macros, vba

After some searching I have found a macro to export an Excel sheet as record in a password protected Access database

```vb
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
Dim dbPath
Dim i As Long


'add error handling
On Error GoTo errHandler:

'Variables for file path and last row of data
dbPath = ("\\serverpath\reporting.accdb")
'Initialise the collection class variable
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath, , "password"

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

rst.Open Source:="table", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
Options:=adCmdTable

rst.AddNew
For i = 1 To 180
    rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Cells(nextrow, i).Value
Next i
rst.Update

'close the recordset
rst.Close
' Close the connection
cnn.Close
'clear memory
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

'communicate with the user
MsgBox " The data has been successfully sent to the access database"

'Update the sheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:

'clear memory
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Export_Data"
```

I get an error "Error 2147217843 The workgroup information file is missing" at `cnn.Open`

Comment: Look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2cdb0394-b757-4b4c-96e6-927100d8eebd/cannot-start-your-applicationthe-workgroup-information-file-is-missing-or-opened-exclusively-by)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message is misleading.  The problem is not about a MDW (workgroup information file).

There are 2 types of passwords for Access databases:

1. passwords associated with individual Access security user accounts
2. a password which applies to the database itself, and all users must supply that password to open the database

Your password is the second type, but your connection attempt treats it as the first type.

Use the [Jet OLEDB:Database Password](http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/with-database-password/) option in your connection string.

```vb
Dim strConnect As String
strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
    dbPath & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password='password';"
Debug.Print strConnect
cnn.Open strConnect
```

Comment: After switching to legacy encription as recommended in the suggested link the error message is gone. A new error is now popping up: Error 3265 (item cannot be found in the collection) at rst(cells...)

Comment: When you get that error, check what `Cells(1, i).Value` gives you.  Sounds to me like it does not match the name of a column in the recordset (`rst`).

Comment: I suspected the reason being the record ID, which is in the database but not in the source file. I removed it from the db but still get the same error. More investigation needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing the info about the workgroup file, though I believe it primarily is for mdb files:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Test\Test.accdb;User ID=Admin;Jet OLEDB:System database=D:\Test\System.mdw;
```

Comment: This gives the same error message (paths changed to the actual ones. I assume you imply the .mdw file is stored in the same location of the db)

Comment: Well, it was just an example. You will, of course, have to change the path to that of your current setup.

Comment: Is my assumption correct, or can the .mdw file be stored somewhere else? How do I find it?

Comment: It may be found here: _C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access_ but by second thought I don't believe it will work with accdb files, only mdb files. So the pointer is to the answer from Hans.